# Titanium.UI.Button property image is not working as given in document

Tags: android, image, button, titanium, appcelerator

I want to display icon on button with text. I am using following code for this.

```
 var refreshButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        image :'refresh.jpg',
        top : 0,
        height : 100,
        left : width,
        width : width,
        title : 'Refresh'
    })
```

from appcelerator api doc.

> image:     the image to display on the button to the left of the
>   title

but working like backgroundImage

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. I found two different documentations on Titanium.UI.Button with different summary for `image`. [Link 1](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.UI.Button) and [Link 2](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Button-object)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.

But it's not happening when the image is smaller than the button.

I used an image with the size of 1/4th of my button and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the image as an image view in the button:

```
    var button = Ti.UI.createButton({backgroundColor:'black',title:'General Info',textAlign:'left',width:210, height:30,top:20,left:20, color:'white', font:{fontFamily:'AppleGothic',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:20}}); 

    var icon = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : "../images/icon.png",
        height : 20,
        width  :20,
        left : 5
    });

button.add(icon)
```